# Create a function to create a variable inside the class #PYTHON

Tags: python, string, function, class, selenium-webdriver

```
# PYTHON CLASS

@dataclass
class Business:
   Job_Trade: str = None    #Function Creating for this string Function Variable
```

I want a function that creates this variable "Job_Trade: str = None" inside the "class Business"
And with the change of "Job_Trade" name. Called with a new name each time.

Comment: Why do you need to be able to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you need this but you can use `setattr`.

Try this

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Business:
    # Job_Trade: str = None
    pass

def add_variable(class_name, variable_name):
    setattr(class_name, variable_name, None) # Default Value is `None`

# Test the function
add_variable(Business, "Job_Trade")
print(Business.Job_Trade)  # Output: None


Business.Job_Trade = "Something"
print(Business.Job_Trade)  # Output: Something
```